# Sampling Frequency sine wave

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, frequency, sampling

I am trying to design a bandpass FIR filter using the fdatool in matlab. The input signal is a sine wave at 2kHz corrupted by white noise with zero mean and 0.01 variance. I have the required specs for the FIR filter to enhance the sine wave and reduce noise but I am left wondering what sampling frequency should I use. This is what i tried and its not working very well.

```
Fs=10000;
t=0:1/Fs:0.005;
x = sin(2*pi*2000*t);
signal = x + sqrt(0.01)*randn(size(t));
plot(t,signal);
hold on;
output=filter(Hd,signal);
plot(t,output);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a digital FIR filter you should have a certain number of 'taps', or filter coefficients which define the filter. The number of taps will depend on a few things:

1.) the signal sampling frequency

2.) the filter's frequency response

Given that you seem to be choosing an arbitrary `Fs` in your example, I'm left to assume that you haven't chosen an `Fs` on the `fdatool` interface. You should make sure that the sampling frequency of the filter and that of the signal you're generating are the same.